# 3D view doesn't change in spite of pressing numpad

Tags: 3d-view

I'm using Blender 2.8 and I'm facing a problem concerning the 3D view.

In Blender 2.79 I can change the point of view by pressing numpad (1,3,7...). But in Blender 2.8 I have to press numpad **twice** to change the point of view. It seems like the 3D view isn't reloaded when pressing numpad just once.

As a supplement explanation, there is no problem in Rendering mode (either EEVEE or cycles).

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! What do you mean when you say that there is no problem in rendering mode? Could you please explain that point a bit further?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I mean that  I can change the point of view when pressing numpad just once in rendering mode.

Comment: rendering mode means displaying render preview.